# 'Build canceled' Xamarin message when trying to launch default project in Android emulator

Tags: xamarin.android

In both VS2017 (15.9.12) and VS2019 (16.1.1) I cannot run even the simplest Android project in the Android simulator in VS. In both versions of VS, when you create an Android project, it starts you off with a very simple bit of scaffolding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TruckerCert"
             x:Class="TruckerCert.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Without changing a thing, I try to run/debug that and view the app in the Android simulator but I cannot. It compiles fine, but when I try to run it, I see the timid little message in the bottom left (after 1-2 seconds) "Build canceled".

I have changed nothing, and I'm just trying to run VS's built-in sample/startup project. During installation I accepted all the prompts, and some SDK things downloaded. I have restarted VS (both) and rebooted my PC (a few times).

There's a pulldown menu (with play icon to left) at the top of VS with just 1 entry in it: **Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo (Android 8.1 - API 27)**

Alternatively, when I open `Android Device Manager`, I see an entry with the same as in the pulldown and with a Start icon to the right. So I click that, and I get the error dialog:

[image]

I have no idea what that error means or how to solve it. What can I do?

Comment: You have all three things for Hyper-V installed in Windows Features like this link?https://imgur.com/a/EvHHVQf   , you needed a reboot after an update that added the Windows Hypervisor Platform. Note: the minimum version of win10 is at least 1803 if you used Windows Hypervisor Platform.

Comment: I'm trying to get this set up...but why is Hyper-V required for Android emulator? What does an android emulator have to do with a VM?

Comment: That seems to have solved it, but now my app won't launch in the emulator. It launches and immediately stops, with an error that the app stopped. I guess I should make a new questions for that.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your update, is the comment helpful? If so, can I post it to answer, it will help others who have simialr issue.

Comment: Yes, I'll accept. Additionally, I got this working. I had endless trouble with Xamarin in VS2019, so I opened the same project in VS2017 (that I had created in VS2019) and had more endless trouble. But when I started a new fresh xamarin project in VS2017, everything worked like magic. VS2019 for xamarin is BUGGY!

Answer (score 0):

You have all three things for Hyper-V installed in Windows Features like this link?imgur.com/a/EvHHVQf , you needed a reboot after an update that added the Windows Hypervisor Platform. Note: the minimum version of win10 is at least 1803 if you used Windows Hypervisor Platform.